# Font in FIFA and FIFA World Cup logos

Tags: font-identification

I know that the font for the words 'RUSSIA 2018' is called Dusha. What is the font for the words 'FIFA WORLD CUP'. Is there any similar freely available font?

[image]

Comment: It looks like some version of Frutiger with a modified F.  Not everything is a font you can download. Sometimes logo text can be custom designed, or modified from an existing font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is similar to **Graphein Pro** with **Modification of F**. you can modify F after convert font to shape.

[image]

font Graphein Pro from **https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/fontsite/graphein-pro?utm_source=fontsquirrel.com&utm_medium=matcherator_link&utm_campaign=grapheinpro**

Author FontSite Inc.